# Thread vs Handler vs Async task for sockets in android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-handler

I'm going to write an `Android` server socket to connect with a `Windows` client.

Which one is the best between `Thread`, `Handler` and `Async task`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use both a `Thread` or an `AsyncTask`, just chose one of the two based on your needs (if you provide more details about the task you need to perform  I might be able to help you more specifically).

The `Handler` class is not meant to be used to run asynchronous tasks (like `Thread` and `AsyncTask`), an `Handler` instance is used to allow communication between two threads, for instance, if you decide to use the `Thread` over the `AsyncTask`, an `Handler` class will help you with data exchange between your UIThread and the Thread that handles the socket.

---

Now, `AsyncTask`s are perfect for working as a Client. If what you need is opening a Server socket you should forget about those and try to have a look at the `Service` and choose between `Service` and `Thread`.

Why?

Because `AsyncTask` are meant to perform a specific job in a relatively little time. To open a server, which will need to stay opened for (possibly) a long time that's not the class you need.

I'd take a look at the `Service` because it provides some useful methods to interact with the Android application lifecycle.

Comment: I don't know why i didn't think about services, but thanks i'll try to use it

Comment: @AhmedAli I've linked the AsyncTask and Service documentation

Comment: Thanks, i'll see it